# How to accurately measure the effort required to reduce a λ-term?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Blockchains such as Ethereum use a stack-register based language on their smart-contract processing virtual machines. That model is very convenient because it provides a simple mechanism to measure the amount of work required to run programs: just fix a cost for each primitive operation and sum.

Suppose that, instead of virtual machines, a blockchain featuring smart-contracts used a functional programming language such as Haskell's core. Is there any simple, accurate way to measure the amount of work required to execute a functional program - keeping in mind that nodes are able to use any evaluation strategy, so such measurement must be universal.

Comment: Such a measure can not be independet of evaluation strategy. Outermost evaluation will reduce terms to normal form, that innermost won't. For example `const () (fix id)`. With outermost evaluation this term will be reduced to normal form in one step. With innermost evaluation this will execute the infinite loop `fix id`, so the cost would be infinite. `fix` is from `Data.Function`.

Comment: Well actually it would be independent of evaluation strategy if you define it as the minimum number of steps to reduce a term to normal form over all possible evaluation strategies. But that would be equal to the number of steps needed when using lazy evaluation and I don't think this would be a useful measure for any other evaluation strategy.

Comment: By step I mean applying a lambda abstraction to **one** argument or applying a primitive operation its arguments.

Comment: @jpath Are you sure about the lazy strategy being an optimal evaluation strategy? I thought optimality was more complex.

Comment: Then it is not viable to replace such machine with a functional core?

Comment: I think this requires defining a cost model for term reduction. I'm pretty sure this has been done, albeit a single "winner" cost model for FP has not emerged.

Comment: @chi I'm sure my professor said that...

Comment: Cost model example: you could e.g. perform leftmost-outermost beta steps, and pay a price (e.g. Ethereum "gas") for every substitution `M{N/x}` which is `size(M)*size(N)` (or `size(M{N/x})`, or ...). Better (in some sense) formulas surely exist.

Comment: @jpath Mhhh not sure. If we evaluate `map (\x -> id id id x) [1..5]` in a lazy way, then `id id id` gets evaluated 5 times, I think.

Comment: @chi that is a progress, but it seems to overcharge for linear terms and undercharge for terms with tons of copies of `x` (which could possibly be a room for attack: send for the blockchain terms whose beta-reductions take exponential time on their size).

Comment: @MaiaVictor I think evaluation strategy is part of a language definition, because you can not write a program for one evaluation strategy and expect it to work with any other strategy. So if you define the evaluation strategy the problem goes away.

Comment: @MaiaVictor Agreed, it's not ideal. Perhaps for Ethereum-related purposes a bit of overcharging is OK, the important aspect is to not undercharge (for attacks, as you say). By the way, isn't the cost above proportional to the number of copies anyway?

Comment: @chi Lazy evaluation is not just outermost evaluation, but outermost evaluation with memorisation. So `id id id` should only be evaluated once.

Comment: @jpath you can't force nodes to run a specific strategy... in practice some nodes will find different evaluation strategies for some terms to gain an advantage.

Comment: @chi ah, I think it is. Interesting idea, then. So this never undercharges, but overcharges often, right? That might be an issue for user experience, but might be good enough to work.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I think so. Probably `size(M{N/x})` is better, even if it overcharges since it does not take sharing into account.

Comment: @MaiaVictor If your cost model is based on outermost evaluation, they will have to use outermost otherwise they won't be able to reduce terms with finite cost. What they can do is use optimisations like strictness analysis and sharing/memorisation to be more efficient in some cases. If you base your model around innermost evaluation they can use outermost or innermost evaluation but programmers can not make use of the benefits of outermost evaluation.

Comment: "in practice some nodes will find different evaluation strategies for some terms to gain an advantage." Why doesn't this apply equally to an imperative stack-register machine language?

Answer (score 1):

"just fix a cost for each primitive operation and sum" is not easy to do. A blockchain network dynamically determines the true value of its token for whatever value the minimum of its token provides. For eg, a gas is worth whatever the world wants to pay for it to use it as a unit of calculation on the world computer. To accurately measure the effort spent by the network to ensure the unit value of its token , we need a DMMS algorithm(as described in the sidechains paper) & which is nothing but a proof-of-work blockchain.

Each primitive operation needs its own blockchain for its value to be determined accurately. When multiple token are implemented over a single blockchain, for eg colored/custom coins, it cannot accurately measure the value of a unit.

In case of functional language, one could perhaps imagine a lisp blockchain with paul graham's 7 primitives implemented as an opcode (stack based interpretor is irrelevant), which would be turing complete but will suffer from the problem of determining the true value of each opcode; the cheapest one will always be abused as evident on ethereum (suicide function's cheapness was spammed).

Thus, to achieve a functional turing complete blockchain you need a braid network of 7 blockchains, each independently determining the true value of effort required for that primitive calculation.

People who have alternatives to proof-of-work will disagree with the above. Cryptocurrency is a new field and the maths is not mature enough for anyone to make concrete claims.